# view items in SessionState, httpcontext, in visualstudio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a way to view all of them items that are being stored in the current HTTP session state?

This might be really stupid, but I need to figure out if my values are actually being sent to the HttpContext session.

I'm using VS 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I figured this out.

You just have to hover over where you declare HttpContext for the first time.